# Ошибка при запуске сценария написанного на русском

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

При попытке запуска сценария на русском языке (язык gherkin, feature файл) при компиляции вываливается одна из следующих ошибок:

До смены языка системы в настройке "региональные стандарты":

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '?' near index 3
^???????? ??????????? ? ??? ????????$
```

После смены языка системы:

```
Exception in thread "main" cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Failed to parse resource at: file:/C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/proj/src/test/resources/features/???????????.feature
```

Пробовал изменять настройку кодировок в IDE, никакого эффекта.